# With GraphQLSchema, is there syntax to modularlize GraphQLObjectTypes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, graphql-schema

How do I refactor userThat (and likely several other related fields) into other nice modular files and then include them into root_query_type.js

This is a vanilla node/express/graphql GraphQLObjectType implementation.

Or am I destined to have a huge root_query_type.js ?

schema.js

```
module.exports = new GraphQLSchema({
  query: RootQueryType
});
```

root_query_type.js

```
const RootQueryType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'RootQueryType',
  fields: {
    userThis: {
      type: UserType,
      resolve(parentValue, args, request) {
        return thisResult;
      }
    },
    userThat: {
      type: UserType,
      args: {
        thatArgs: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) },
      },
      resolve: (parentValue, arg, request) => {
        return thatResult;
      },
    },
```

Comment: There's nothing special about GraphQL here. You just have a large object literal - and you can split that apart into the individual properties, and import each value from a separate module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I usually do:

```js
// user.js

const User = new GraphQLObjectType({ ... });

const queryFields = {
  userThis: {
    type: UserType,
    resolve(parentValue, args, request) {
      return thisResult;
    }
  },
};

const mutationFields = { ... };

module.exports = { User, queryFields, mutationFields };
```

```js
// RootQueryType.js

// rename queryFields to userQueryFields as we might want to import queryFields
// from many different modules
const { queryFields: userQueryFields } = require('./modules/user.js');

const RootQueryType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'RootQueryType',
  fields: {
    ...userQueryFields,
  },
});
```